# How can I preview Google Chrome in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: browser, text, preview

I cannot figure out how to open Google Chrome by default via the "Preview in Browser" plugin for Sublime Text 3. I've read up on the documentation [here](https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser)
but I didn't understand the instructions. He told me to navigate to Preferences > package settings > view in browser but that's it.. I'm not sure if I should click the default settings (which I can't seem to modify) or the user settings. I'm not sure what to type either.

Right now it works just fine with Firefox but I'd really like it to work with Chrome. If anybody has any idea what I can do to get this working that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was not far away ;)
Goto `Preferences > Package Settings > View in Browser > Settings - User`
and write this:

```
{
    "browser": "chrome64" //64 bit
    "browser": "chrome"   //32 bit
}
```

Save and close the file. This should open Chrome by default when you start the plugin.

In General, `Settings - Default` should never be touched, because changes will be overwritten on updates. If you want to customize plugins, always do it in `Settings - User`. Most of the time, it helps to have a look at the default file in order to know what to write in the user file.

Comment: Sadly I tried that and for some reason it didn't work, thanks though.

Comment: Try `chrome64` instead of `chrome`.

Answer (score 0):

If it didn't work for you it is because Phillip missed comma after "chrome64" :)
It should be:

```
{
        "browser": "chrome64", //64 bit
        "browser": "chrome"   //32 bit
    }
```